# Configure JBoss EAP 7 with HTTPS TLS 1.2

Tags: java, http, https, jboss

I am trying to configure a JBOSS EAP 7.0 server to use HTTPS and TLS 1.2.

I have created a certificcate using the command:

```
keytool -keystore <PATH>\keystore2.jks -alias servercert -validity 365 -genkey
```

I have then added the following to the standalone.xml using the cli tool.

```
            <security-realm name="HTTPSRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="<PATH>\keystore2.jks" keystore-password="password" alias="servercert"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
```

...

```
<https-listener name="https" security-realm="HTTPSRealm" socket-binding="https"/>
```

The port binding for HTTPS is

```
       <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8082}"/>
```

When I try and access my web application using https on port 8082 I get a connection closed error from my browswer.

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong and how to enable HTTPS?  There doesn't seem to be any errors being created in the logs and the listener is listed on start-up.

Answer (score 0):

The Certificate seemed to be broken I generated another one and it worked fine.